# Pointers inside function in C

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>

int q = 10;

void fun(int *p){
    *p = 15;
    p = &q;
    printf("%d ",*p);
}    

int main(){
  int r = 20;
  int *p = &r;  
  fun(p);
  printf("%d", *p);
  return 0;
}
```

I was playing with pointers. Could not understand the output of this.
Output is coming as 10 15.
Once p is pointing to address of q, why on returning to main function it's value changes? Also why it changed to the value '15' which was assigned to it in the function before '10'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `p` is `fun()` is not the same `p` in `main()`. `p` , in each function, is local. So changing one doesn't affect other.

Comment: But it is showing output as 15 inside main! It should be 20 then

Comment: Because you are chaning the value point to by `p` in fun() with:     `*p = 15;` Note that there is a difference in changing the value of *pointer* and what it's *point to*.

Answer (score 4):

In C, *all* function parameters are passed by value, including pointers.

`*p = 15;` *will* set `r` to 15 as `*p` is pointing to the memory occupied by `r` in `main()` prior to its reassignment to `&q`;

Your reassignment `p = &q;` does *not* change what `p` points to in the caller `main()`. To do that, you'd need to doubly indirect the pointer, i.e. change the function prototype to `void fun(int **p){`, call it using `fun(&p);`, and reassign using `*p = &q;`.

Comment: Then how come it is showing 15 as output inside main function?

Answer (score 1):

Two steps:

1. First call to `fun()`, assigning the address of global `int q` [holding value 10] to `p` *inside the fucntion scope* and printing it. The first output ==> `10`;
2. Once the call returns from `fun()`, it will hold the previous address, [passed from `main()`] and hence, will print the value held by that address [which is `15`, modified inside `fun()`].